# image wont show through transparent sphere

Tags: image, transparency

I have imported image as plane, and set the blend mode to opaque (using EEVEE). I have a transparent sphere, but it wont show through the image.

Ps: Just to make sure my sphere is transparent I inserted an icosphere.

[image]

Comment: hello, could you please pack your image and share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/a844f58f0c704d09afe5e9f9fab3806d

Comment: could you please say what doesn't show exactly? I can see the image through the sphere, it's just that it deforms a lot, but if you give your material a IOR of 1 you'll see it flat

Comment: Ok, you're correct, I set up, a glass & transparent material, and lowered the IOR and I can see through it. The previous material of the sphere was a basic material with 100% transmission. I'll keep in mind this node set up for more control on transparent objects. 
https://ibb.co/D97ZkHr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the image through the sphere, it's just that it deforms a lot, but if you give your material a *IOR* of 1 you'll see it flat.